# Create database schema based on ajax response data

Tags: sql-server, json, ajax, xml, rdbms

I want to reproduce the database schema of private sever based on the data that returns by ajax response. My steps: convert json to xml and use it as database schema.

I want to use SQL Server 2012 as RDBMS but don't know how to import xml as database schema. (I know about PostgreSQL which perfecty works with xml but I need SQL Server)

May be there are any tools in SQL Server or external? Or any ideas how to create database schema based on ajax response data.

Comment: You could create serializable/deserializable c# classes and use a code first approach.

Comment: There will be no *out of the box* behaviour to transform *any XML* into neatly designed relational structures. It would help to see an example of your XML...